# How to use Reap and Sow instead of Append to

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap

I have matrix and and i want to do increment in a do loop and and i want to store in list using append to. It works fine for less values, But when i want to do it for values around 1 million the program is slow.

```
 x = {{0.1},{0.2}};xm = {{0.4},{0.5}};
Do[datax[i] = {}; dataxm[i] = {};, {i, 1, 2}]

Do[
 x = x + t;
xm = xm + t;
 Do[AppendTo[datax[i], Flatten[{t, x[[i]]}]];, {i, 1, 2}];
Do[AppendTo[dataxm[i], Flatten[{t, xm[[i]]}]];, {i, 1, 2}], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]


 datax[1]

 {{0., 0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.4, 1.1}, {0.5, 1.6}, {0.6, 2.2}, {0.7, 2.9}, {0.8, 3.7}, {0.9, 4.6}, {1., 5.6}}

datax[2]

{{0., 0.2}, {0.1, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.8}, {0.4, 1.2}, {0.5, 
  1.7}, {0.6, 2.3}, {0.7, 3.}, {0.8, 3.8}, {0.9, 4.7}, {1., 5.7}}

dataxm[1]

 {{0., 0.4}, {0.1, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.7}, {0.3, 1.}, {0.4, 
  1.4}, {0.5, 1.9}, {0.6, 2.5}, {0.7, 3.2}, {0.8, 4.}, {0.9, 
  4.9}, {1., 5.9}}

 dataxm[2]

 {{0., 0.5}, {0.1, 0.6}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.3, 1.1}, {0.4, 
  1.5}, {0.5, 2.}, {0.6, 2.6}, {0.7, 3.3}, {0.8, 4.1}, {0.9, 5.}, {1.,
   6.}}
```

Similar to the above I want to use reap and sow functions to speed it up but i can store only the last value. Why?

```
 x = {{0.1},{0.2}};xm = {{0.4},{0.5}};


Do[
x = x + t;xm = xm + t;

Do[datax[i] = Reap[Sow[{t, x[[i]]}]][[2, 1]], {i, 1, 2}];

Do[dataxm[i] = Reap[Sow[{t, xm[[i]]}]][[2, 1]], {i, 1, 2}];


, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]

datax[1]
{{1., {5.6}}}

 datax[2]
{{1., {5.7}}}


datax[1]
{{1., {5.9}}}

datax[2]
{{1., {6.0}}
```

Can anyone help in fixing this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need only one `Reap` for all `Sow`s -- that's primarily the advantage of using them.

Moreover, you may use tags to obtain `datax[1]` and `datax[2]`:

```
x = {{0.1}, {0.2}};
ClearAll[datax];
datax = Association@Reap[
    Do[
     x = x + t;
     Do[
      Sow[
       Flatten[{t, x[[tag]]}], 
       tag
       ],
      {tag, 1, 2}],
     {t, 0, 1, 0.1}],
    _, Rule][[2]]
```

> <|1 -> {{0., 0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.4,
> 1.1}, {0.5, 1.6}, {0.6, 2.2}, {0.7, 2.9}, {0.8, 3.7}, {0.9,
> 4.6}, {1., 5.6}},
> 2 -> {{0., 0.2}, {0.1, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.8}, {0.4,
> 1.2}, {0.5, 1.7}, {0.6, 2.3}, {0.7, 3.}, {0.8, 3.8}, {0.9,
> 4.7}, {1., 5.7}}|>

Now you can access `datax[1]` and `datax[2]` as before.

**Edit:**

Because the question changed: This should allow you to assemble more than one list in one go:

```
data = Merge[
   Reap[
     Do[
      x = x + t;
      xm = xm + t;
      Do[
       Sow[Flatten[{t, x[[i]]}], "datax" -> i];
       Sow[Flatten[{t, xm[[i]]}], "dataxm" -> i]
       ,
       {i, 1, 2}], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}],
     _, #1[[1]] -> Association[#1[[2]] -> #2] &][[2]]
   , Association
   ];
```

Now `data["datax"]` and `data["dataxm"]` should behave like `datax` and `dataxm`.

**Edit 2**

You can obtain essentially the same result much more efficiently with arrays produced by `Table`:

```
x = {0.1, 0.2};
xm = {0.4, 0.5};
{datax, dataxm} = Transpose[
   Table[{{{t, t}, x += t}, {{t, t}, xm += t}}, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
   {3, 1, 4, 2}];
```

Now you have (notice the double brackets):

```
datax[[1]]
datax[[2]]
dataxm[[1]]
dataxm[[2]]
```

**Speed considerations**

Even faster for this particular problem is to avoid recursive addition and to use vectorized operations.

The `Reap`/`Sow` method from above:

```
n = 1000000;

x = {0.1, 0.2};
xm = {0.4, 0.5};
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  data = Merge[
     Reap[
       Do[
        x = x + t;
        xm = xm + t;
        Do[
         Sow[Flatten[{t, x[[i]]}], "datax" -> i];
         Sow[Flatten[{t, xm[[i]]}], "dataxm" -> i]
         ,
         {i, 1, 2}], {t, 0., 1., 1./n}],
       _, #1[[1]] -> Association[#1[[2]] -> #2] &][[2]]
     , Association
     ];
  ]
```

> 11.4845

The `Table` method from above:

```
x = {0.1, 0.2};
xm = {0.4, 0.5};
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  {datax, dataxm} = 
    Transpose[
     Table[{{{t, t}, x += t}, {{t, t}, xm += t}}, {t, 0., 1., 
       1./n}], {3, 1, 4, 2}];
  ]
```

> 2.74062

Vectorized version:

```
x = {0.1, 0.2};
xm = {0.4, 0.5};
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  tlist = Subdivide[0., 1., n];
  slist = Accumulate[tlist];
  datax2 = {
    Transpose[{tlist, x[[1]] + slist}],
    Transpose[{tlist, x[[2]] + slist}]
    };
  dataxm2 = {
    Transpose[{tlist, xm[[1]] + slist}],
    Transpose[{tlist, xm[[2]] + slist}]
    };
  ]
```

> 0.061355

So, the latter is 187 or 44 times faster than the methods before. So you should take these considerations into account when using `Reap` and `Sow`.

Errors:

```
Max[Abs[data["datax"][1] - datax[[1]]]]
Max[Abs[data["datax"][2] - datax[[2]]]]
Max[Abs[data["dataxm"][1] - dataxm[[1]]]]
Max[Abs[data["dataxm"][2] - dataxm[[2]]]]
Max[Abs[datax - datax2]]
Max[Abs[dataxm - dataxm2]]
```

> 0. 
> 1. 
> 2. 
> 3. 
>
> 5.82077*10^-11
>
> 5.82077*10^-11

Comment: Sir Thanks for the reply. The method which you provided above works fine if i can i have only one list. Actually i edited the post can you fix the problem with above example. I wanted to store x and xm in different list is it possible . If cannot how can i extract the values with same tag for x and xm