# Using Reap instead of AppendTo

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two expressions and three loops as

```
    f[x_, y_, z_] := (y + z^2) Exp[-I x] + (x + z^2) Exp[-I y];
    g[x_, y_, z_] := Abs[Conjugate[f[x, y, z]]*f[x + 1, y + 1, z + 2]];

list = {};
Do[
 Do[
  Do[
   AppendTo[list, {x, g[x, y, z]}];
   
   , {x, 0, 10, 0.05}]
  , {y, 1, 10}]
 , {z, -50, 50, 10}]
```

Bu I wish to use `Reap` and `Sow` instead of `AppendTo` and three loops. However I have seen the document and help of *Mathematica* about this subject, I did not understand very well how I can exploit of `Reap` because of few examples in the help.

Comment: Have you seen [`Henrik's explanation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185662/how-to-use-reap-and-sow-instead-of-append-to/185665#185665)? I think it's very helpful.

Comment: I have not seen that post. I think it is good

Comment: If you just want to build up a list, wouldn't Table or some other structure-building function be simpler (and faster)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works and reproduces precisely the result of the OP.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := (y + z^2) Exp[-I x] + (x + z^2) Exp[-I y];
g[x_, y_, z_] := Abs[Conjugate[f[x, y, z]]*f[x + 1, y + 1, z + 2]];
```

Code from OP

```
list = {};
Do[
 Do[
  Do[
   AppendTo[
     list, {x, g[x, y, z]}];,
   {x, 0, 10, 0.05}],
  {y, 1, 10}],
 {z, -50, 50, 10}]
```

### **Using [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) + [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)**

```
rslist = Reap[
    Do
     [Do
      [Do
       [Sow[{x, g[x, y, z]}], {x, 0, 10, 0.05}],
      {y, 1, 10}],
     {z, -50, 50, 10}]][[-1, 1]];
```

### **Checking they are precisely the same**

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[list - rslist]
```

> `True`

The following also tests if the `Array` is zero

```
test = Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ[#] && #[[1]] == 0 &;


test@(Flatten[Rationalize[list - rslist, 0]])
```

> `True`

Answer (score 9):

why not

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = (y + z^2) Exp[-I x] + (x + z^2) Exp[-I y];
g[x_, y_, z_] = Abs[Conjugate[f[x, y, z]]*f[x + 1, y + 1, z + 2]];
Table[{x, g[x, y, z]}, {z, -50, 50, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {x, 0, 10, 0.05}]//Flatten[#,2]&
```

---

if you do want reap and sow

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = (y + z^2) Exp[-I x] + (x + z^2) Exp[-I y];
g[x_, y_, z_] = Abs[Conjugate[f[x, y, z]]*f[x + 1, y + 1, z + 2]];
Reap[Do[
  Sow[{x, g[x, y, z]}]
, {z, -50, 50, 10}
, {y, 1, 10}
, {x, 0, 10, 0.05}
 ]][[-1,1]]
```

Comment: (+1) for elegance and simplicity!!!